# How to display a secured on-premise Power BI Report Server report in a Blazor Server app

Tags: asp.net-core, iframe, powerbi, blazor

In my Blazor server app, I'd like to display iframes with an on-premise Power BI Report Server report in them (using **?rs:embed=true**). The report server is separate from the app server but within our corporate network. SQL Database is another server. All servers are HTTPS with users using their active directory accounts for access.

Currently when my Blazor app is loading the user is prompted to login by the browser (no login page within the app). Then when the home page encounters an iframe containing a PBI Report, they are prompted to login again and again for each iframe.

Also, my app has anchor tags leading users to launch reports in a separate window. Since the iframe reports have connected to the report server, these reports don't request login. BTW, before I added the iframes, the anchor tag calls to reports would request a login once - all subsequent report request would not request login.

I'd like to have the user only have to login once.

Currently using .NET Core 7 but could upgrade to 8 if that will make things easier? (App not in production yet)

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: The login prompt you are getting is expected behavior. if you upgrade .net version it wont help you directly solve the issue.it might can help you provide more features. as alternative approach you could try some other authentication method like SSO , token based authentication or something else that can help you avoid this login prompt every time